# apache2 django mod_wsgi htaccess

Tags: django, apache, apache2

I want to have Apache serving .htaccess file to fix firefox Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
I'm using mod_wsgi and my httpd.conf looks like this:

```
Alias /static/ /home/ubuntu/my-django-app/static/

<Directory /home/ubuntu/my-django-app/static>
Order deny, allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/my-django-app/apache/django.wsgi
```

What do I have to do to get Apache look for .htaccess file in /home/ubuntu/my-django-app?

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the httpd.conf, you can probably take care of your configuration needs for Access-Control-Allow-Origin there.